# Getting page with fsockopen

Tags: php, sockets, fsockopen, phpwebsocket

I'm trying to access `http://www.example.com:4380/apid/request?method=getXMLTable&name=1&ui=UI&id=12345`. It should give back output as XML.
This is the code:

```
<?

$host = "www.example.com";
$path = "/apid/request?method=getXMLTable&name=1&ui=UI&id=12345";
$port = 4380;

$fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);
$buffer ="";
if (!$fp) {
      echo "ERR!!<br>";
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET ".$path." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $out .= "Host: ".$host."\r\n";
        $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
        fwrite($fp, $out);
    
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $buffer .= fgets($fp, 1024);
        }
        fclose($fp);
}                                                            
 ?>
```

Anyhow I'm getting not the XML output, but this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Last-Modified: Wed, 02 Apr 2014 16:16:43 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Cache-Control: pre-check=0
Cache-Control: post-check=0
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Wed, 02 Apr 2014 16:16:43 GMT
Connection: close 2000 0
```

I can access pages like `'www.example.com/path/to/file'` with the presented code without any problems. I guess I make any mistake with port(not standard http ) or request. Every clue would be very welcome.

## EDIT:

I `can't` use any http module! Socket is a must in this case!
I have tried with the code below, but I get nothing in $body:

```
list($header, $body) = explode("\n\n", $buffer, 2);
echo http_chunked_decode($body);
```

Comment: When you use `fsockopen` you get all the HTTP response headers before the page content. Why don't you use `file_get_contents`?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` response. You need to use `http_chunked_decode` to decode it (you can find a [PHP version here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-chunked-decode.php), if you don't have `pecl_http`).

```
list($header, $body) = explode("\n\n", $buffer, 2);
echo http_chunked_decode($body);
```

But as the other commenter said, you should really use `file_get_contents` if you have `allow_url_fopen` enabled or [curl](http://php.net/curl) otherwise. They handle the chunked encoding for you.

Comment: It gives me NULL in $body. As you can see, there are headers only in $buffer, so split won't work... BTW it should be $body, not body. I can't edit, cause the correction is too short

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure if you were only posting the start of the output. Do you get the correct output when you access the URL directly, say with curl?

Comment: Yes, i get output while accessing the URL directly.

Comment: Try mimicking the headers used by `curl`. For example, maybe the script expects a `User-Agent`